# How to enable embedded image in rails sanitize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, sanitize, data-uri

I would like to use embedded images in rails, like this:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

In my view I use sanitize to filter html tags, like this:

```
sanitize @post.body,
         tags: %w(h1 h2 span code a img pre strong u em s sub sup ol li ul blockquote),
         attributes: %w(class style href width height src alt)
```

As you can see I enable img element and src attribute, but sanitize filters out src attribute in case of embedded images (data URI scheme). In case of "normal" images (where src is a normal link), it works correctly.

How can I tell sanitize to enable embedded images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enable data protocol with the following code:

```
HTML::WhiteListSanitizer.allowed_protocols << 'data'
```

I use it in config/initializers/sanitize.rb , and now it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The newest `loofah` already include `data` in the `ACCEPTABLE_PROTOCOLS`.

https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/d0634bd21c70cd08742cde4cbd7b60feac249e80/lib/loofah/html5/whitelist.rb#L147

just type `bundle update loofah`